# Is there a way to remove the N/A boxplots when you select specific rows to visualize?

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2

So I made a boxplot using ggplot with the code below

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = factor(Letters, level = c("A", "B", "C", "D")), y = Expression)) + geom_boxplot() + 
  scale_x_discrete(guide = guide_axis(n.dodge=3)) + xlab("Letters") + ylab("Expression")
```

The plot that is generated is good except that all the Letters in the dataframe that haven't been called "E-Z" also are shown in the plot under the category NA. But I don't want the NA category to be shown. You may be thinking why don't I just delete those rows that I don't want visualize. The issue is I'm making 6 of these plots with different rows and I was wondering if there's a way of doing it that doesn't involving making 6 dataframes and removing the rows I don't want each and everytime. First 6 rows of the dataframe are shown below

| Letter | Expression |
| --- | --- |
| A | 10 |
| B | 20 |
| C | 15 |
| D | 12 |
| E | 16 |
| F | 18 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pipe your `df` into a `filter()` and then pipe it to `ggplot`. This **will not** change the content of your original dataframe.

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% filter(Letters %in% c("A", "B", "C", "D")) %>%
  ggplot(., aes(x = Letters, y = Expression)) + 
  geom_boxplot() + 
  scale_x_discrete(guide = guide_axis(n.dodge=3)) + 
  xlab("Letters") + 
  ylab("Expression")
```

[image: filter_ggplot]